# Friendly links in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wanted to make seo-friendly URLs, but I have some problems while setting up the .htaccess file. First of all, I've made it possible to get rid of file extension (.php) and the link shows properly.
`example.com/pond.php` => `example.com/pond`
The problem begins when I try to add $_GET variables to the link.

What works for me is either `example.com/pond.php?a=1&b=2` or `example.com/pond?a=1&b=2`.

What I would like to achieve is `example.com/pond-1-2`, but when I go to this link I get site not found

My .htacess file

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#extension removed

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

#RewriteRule ^pond/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) pond.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^pond-(.*)-(.*)$ pond.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^pond-([^\.]+)-([^\.]+)$ pond.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

The commented rules are what I've tried previously, but none of these work for me. I've tried solutions from many topics on stackoverflow, but these also do not work for me :(.

Comment: Do you _understand_ the principle of how this removing of the .php extension works, what these RewriteConds actually _do_? If not, then you should make an effort to go and read up on that first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]`
This was  the solution to my problem.

Comment: What URL are you requesting when this rule triggers? This would seem to match a different URL to that stated in the question?

Comment: @MrWhite I can request any url that I want. Pond.php was one of those I needed.

Comment: Ok, it's just that if you request the URL you gave as an example in the question (ie. `/pond-1-2`) then the above directive will rewrite the request to `pond-1.php?id=2` - which is not the desired result, at least not according what you've stated in your question?

Answer (score 3):

I prepared 3 different examples. I hope it helps you or others.

Version 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^pond([\-]([^-]+))?([\-]([^-]+))?([\-]([^-]+))?$ pond.php?a=$2&b=$4&c=$6 [NC,L]
```

- https://www.example.com/pond
- https://www.example.com/pond-1
- https://www.example.com/pond-1-2
- https://www.example.com/pond-1-2-3

**[Test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=b1543d73-a6b0-499a-ba14-b022efeb595d)**

---

Version 2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pond$ pond.php [L]
RewriteRule ^pond-([^-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pond-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^pond-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
```

- https://www.example.com/pond
- https://www.example.com/pond-1
- https://www.example.com/pond-1-2
- https://www.example.com/pond-1-2-3

**[Test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=586ea867-9885-4868-b25c-655b09056a05)**

---

Version 3:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pond$ pond.php [L]
RewriteRule ^pond/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pond/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^pond/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ pond.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
```

- https://www.example.com/pond
- https://www.example.com/pond/1
- https://www.example.com/pond/1/2
- https://www.example.com/pond/1/2/3

**[Test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=85999c97-d492-432b-a33b-2a9fbfce8689)**